# PHPStorm + docker + xdebug + db ssh tunnel

Tags: docker, ssh-tunnel, phpstorm, xdebug

Locally I have following docker-compose configuration:

```
nginx:
  build:
    context: ./nginx
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
    - ./../logs:/home/web/logs/
    - ./../:/home/web/my-website.com/
  depends_on:
    - php
php:
  build:
    context: ./php
  volumes:
    - ./../:/home/web/my-website.com/
  working_dir: /home/web/my-website.com/
  expose:
    - "8123"
```

`php` container has xdebug installed into it, I can easily connect to it from PHPStorm.
I have remote ClickHouse database which is connected via SSH Tunnel. When I start my container I just go into my container and execute:

```
ssh -4 login@host.com -p 2211 -L 8123:localhost:8123 -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -Nf
```

After this, my site is able to use this connection, but when I execute console command

```
./yii analysis/start-charts 003b56fe-db47-11e8-bcc0-52540010e5bc 205
```

from PHPStorm, I'm getting an exception:

```
Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8123: Connection refused
```

If I jump into the container and launch the same command, everything works fine.

What's wrong? Why PHPStorm doesn't see my ssh tunnel?

**UPD**
I've changed host of clickhouse to docker container and changed `php` container definition to the following:

```
php:
  build:
    context: ./php
  volumes:
    - ./../:/home/web/my-website.com/
  working_dir: /home/web/my-website.com/
  expose:
    - "8123"
  ports:
    - "8123:8123"
```

Now everything works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ssh tunnel is created inside your container on the socket `127.0.0.1:8123`. You expose Port 8123 to the Host (maybe you should expose 127.0.0.1:8123). But the actual problem is that you try to Access `127.0.0.1:8123` from your Host machine, whereas you should access `<ContainerIP>:8123`.

You could try to change the [network_mode](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode) use the `network_mode: "host"` in your compose file as a solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it helped me. But I have to add that I had to add `ports` node to the definition of `php` container. I add this edit to the question